# Can we use same database for php and django?

Tags: php, django, web-applications

#### Scenario

There is an Android app running with php as backend and a webapp running with django. Both apps are designed to be used with same database. Can this approach create any issues ?

Comment: I see no problems with this approach.

Comment: if both backend and web app tries to manipulate data at same time, will cause a big problem.

Comment: @Vishwa what kind of problem , are you saying that if android app and webapp tries to manipulate the data at the same time it can cause problem , if then can you explain further ?

Comment: @Vishwa There will be no problem: databases can handle concurrent writes. Besides, this scenario is no different than a web app writing to the database  from multiple threads at the same time.

Comment: That's right, either way, if rightly implemented, every DB transaction should follow ACID principles and if you `commit` or `save` each transaction as when they happen properly, it should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most suitable answer I found is [Xyres](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1925257/xyres) mentioned ,

There will be no problem: databases can handle concurrent writes. Besides, this scenario is no different than a web app writing to the database from multiple threads at the same time.